# Updating heat map with real-time data

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jquery, websocket

I'm using websockets to send data from the server to the client. This works fine so for example I can display messages the server is sending to the client as they are received. 
I'm able to convert this into longitude and latitudes.

So as data is recieved from the server it should plot onto the map in my html, but it doesn't seem to be plotting anything at all.

I'm completely new to javascript so am unsure if my code is correct. What I would like to ideally do is has soon data is received it is plotted straight onto the map and thus generate the heat map. This is the javascript side of the code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var ws = new WebSocket("ws://" + "localhost" + ":" + "8888" + "/ws");
        var London = new google.maps.LatLng(51.507335, -0.127683);

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
        center: London,
        zoom: 3,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var pointArray = new google.map.MVCArray([]);           
    ws.onmessage = function(evt){  
            //$("#display").append(evt.data + "<br />");

            var msg = JSON.parse(evt.data);
            var coordinates = msg.coordinates.coordinates;
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[1], coordinates[0]);
            console.log('received');
            pointArray.push(latLng);
            var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
                data: pointArray
            });
            heatmap.setMap(map);

            //$("#display").append(latLng + "<br />");

            //console.log(evt.data);

    };

    ws.onclose = function(evt) {alert("Server connection terminated");};
   });      
    $("#open").click(function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    $.post("/", $("#eventForm").serialize());   

});

</script>
```

Would there be a way so that as data is received it's stored into an array, BUT then I'm not sure how then I could update the map with element in the array has it is received. 
Thanks

Comment: please elaborate on the specific issue you're having. attach more relevant information regarding the problem, e.g. error messages from the console. stackoverflow is not a debugging service.

Comment: There are no error messages on the web console. The specific problem is that the coordinate data that I'm receiving fine, is however not being plotted onto the map in the javascript code.

Comment: Why setup a new Websocket connection for each click ?

Comment: @ManseUK....what I'm trying to achieve is that once the connection by the websocket is made then all data received is plotted onto the graph. I didn't mean to to create a new websocket for each click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say for sure if this is the only issue, but you appear to have a scoping issue here -

```
ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
    var msg = JSON.parse(evt.data);
    var coordinates = msg.coordinates.coordinates;
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[1], coordinates[0]);
};
...
var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
    data: latLng
});
```

The way scopes work in javascript is that latLng is only available to code within the function it is declared. An easy way to fix this would be to just declare it in the scope they share -

```
var latLng;
ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
    var msg = JSON.parse(evt.data);
    var coordinates = msg.coordinates.coordinates;
    latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[1], coordinates[0]);
};
...
var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
    data: latLng
});
```

This will make latLng accessible to other parts of the code in the click function.

A few other possible issues:

If you want to progressively add data to a map, your structure is in general a bit off. What you'd want to do is create a single map that's inside the webpage, then continually add data to it - there's no need to create a new map each time. What you probably should be doing is creating the map inside of the ready function, not the click.

Also, there is a single heatmap layer in a google map; if you create new heatmaps for each bit of received data, you'll be overriding everything that you have put into prior heatmaps. Given your most recent edit it looks like you've already reached the same conclusion though.

I'm also not quite sure your websocket code is quite as good as it needs to be. The websocket "onmessage" function will not immediately return results: rather, it provides instructions on how to handle any data that comes in at any point in the future. So, if you want to update the map every time that data comes in, you do not need to do anything with websockets on a click event.

This will lead to code that is loosely structured like this -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ws = new WebSocket("ws://" + "localhost" + ":" + "8888" + "/ws");
    var London = new google.maps.LatLng(51.507335, -0.127683);

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
        center: London,
        zoom: 3,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    });

    var pointArray = new google.map.MVCArray([]);
    ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
        var msg = JSON.parse(evt.data);
        var coordinates = msg.coordinates.coordinates;
        pointArray.push(new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[1], coordinates[0]));
        var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
            data: pointArray
        });
        heatmap.setMap(map);
    };

    $("#open").click(function (evt) {
        // whatever code you want click to do
    });
});
```

I cannot test any of this code as I do not have your specific websocket setup, but hopefully this gives you a better grounding to go from here.

Comment: Yes....I noticed that but it still was unable to rectify the problem of plotting the points onto the map.

Comment: I've updated my answer to contain a fair bit more detail on likely bugs & fixes in your code, hopefully it's enough for you to get it working.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.....and you've been able to explain much clearly what I thought also. I've used your ammendments, but now the problem is that nothing is being recieved by the client. The web console error says "[22:10:22.526] The connection to ws://localhost:8888/ws was interrupted while the page was loading. It relates to "var ws = new WebSocket("ws://" + "localhost" + ":" + "8888" + "/ws");". I've updated my original question to the ammended version.

Comment: Debugging websocket problems remotely will is a little challenging, as they're fairly specific to the environment you're in. I can give a bit of advice on how to handle it though: try to remove as much of the map components as possible, and see if the ws will work if you reduce it to just the ready function and onmessage.

Comment: Thanks for replying....the ws seems to work as when I run the web console the data is coming in and added to an array. I chaged the array to a standard array and checked it in the console, it was working fine. Is it a problem because as data is always being received from the server and pushed to array it stays at that step and so is never actually going to plot the array elements onto the map?

Comment: I'm using both:     <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=visualization">
    </script> and: <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=false"></script>

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Each time the server sends a packet of data to you, it should call onmessage - so, always receiving data shouldn't really be an issue; it will just result in many function calls. Also, when you say that that you checked the array in the console, do you mean that it was working with socket updates?

Comment: Yes there's no problem receiving the data and getting it into the right format for google.maps.LatLng(coordinates). When I checked the array it was being updated by data received from the server via the socket. The problem seems to be actually plotting these coordinates onto the map.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19695/discussion-between-bubbles-and-user94628)